# Why are Crashlytics functions undefined?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, crash, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have installed the cordova-fabric-plugin in my Ionic 2 project. After that, I have extended IonicHandlerError in FabricHandlerError (code below). The problem is that when the cached error arrives, the Crashlytics is defined and all functions appears in console, but when you use that, they are undefined.

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Crashlytics } from '@ionic-native/fabric';

@Injectable()
export class FabricErrorHandler extends IonicErrorHandler {
    constructor (public crashlytics: Crashlytics) {
        super();
    }

    handleError(error: any): void {
        console.log('In Fabric Error Handler');
        console.log(error);
        this.crashlytics.addLog(error.message);
        this.crashlytics.sendCrash();
        console.log('Crashlytics Sended. Error message: '+ error.message);

        super.handleError(error);
    }
}
```

In console stopping in handler error:

```
this.crashlytics
  Crashlytics {}
    __proto__: IonicNativePlugin
   addLog: ƒ ()
   constructor: ƒ Crashlytics()
   recordError: ƒ ()
   sendCrash: ƒ ()
   sendNonFatalCrash: ƒ ()
   setBoolValueForKey: ƒ ()
   setFloatValueForKey: ƒ ()
   setIntValueForKey: ƒ ()
   setStringValueForKey: ƒ ()
   setUserEmail: ƒ ()
   setUserIdentifier: ƒ ()
   setUserName: ƒ ()
   __proto__: Object

this.crashlytics.addLog('ERROR TESTING');
  undefined

this.crashlytics.sendCrash();
  undefined
```

Comment: How are you initialising the plugin ?